# How to split the heat map

Tags: r, heatmap

I Have the following data frame (Screening):

```
Name Q E R
Z.   4 2 4
X.   1 3 1
C.   2 5 6




library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

rnames <- Screening[,1]
mat_data <- data.matrix(Screening[,3:ncol(Screening)])
rownames(mat_data) <- rnames
mat2 = mat_data
mat2[1, 1] = 100000
```

mat2 is now composed of num [1:63, 1:4]

I tried:

```
Heatmap(mat2, col = colorRamp2(c(6, 3, 1, 0), c("red", "orange", "yellow", "#a6e8ed")),  cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE, heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "Inhibition"), column_names_side = "top", row_names_side = "left", row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8), split = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 44, 50, 58, 63))
```

The heat map is correct but not divided (sliced, split).

1) How can I split the heatmap at row 44, 50, 58, 63 and label them A, B, C, D?

2) The name of column are correct but displayed vertically, how can I make them displayed horizontally?

3) I want control the length and width of the squares of the heatmap and place its value (the number) from the table inside it ?

Thank you